# Dynamically add custom input fields and save them to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, web-services

I want to develop an web-service where a user can add *tickets*. Every ticket has got an input text field *title* and a textarea *description*. If the user klick the *save* button, the data will be saved in a mysql database.

The admin has got an admin panel. He can add or remove input fields in this admin panel to change the *add ticket* view form the user.
For example: The admin adds a select field *category*. You can select category *A*, *B* or *C*. If you select category A, there will be a new input text field called *animal*. If you select category B, nothing happens. If you select category C, there will be 2 new fields: A text field and a number field. The number field is required. And so on, and so on. After a week, the admin could remove some fields, or add a category or... To conclude, the admin can add and remove select, text, number, password,... fields to the *add ticket* section with relationships, length and requirements.

I dont know how to structure the database and to save the data. I think about something like a mysql table `tickets` with `title`, `desc`, and `data` and put an XML / JSON String to the `data` field and another table `ticketFields` with `name` (category, animal,...), `type` (text, number,...), `required` (yes/no), `length` (int), `data` (to store data for select fields). The problem is, that the relationships are missing in this model. So how can I save this data efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relational model might look like this:

**Ticket**:
id PK

**Answer**:
ticketId FK PK
fieldId FK PK
value

**Field**:
id PK,
name,
parentFieldId NULL FK,
parentFieldValue NULL,
type,
required,
min NULL,
max NULL,
range NULL
*(...other "constraint" fields, checked regarding choosen type)*

At first, fields with parentFieldId of NULL are displayed. Fields having parentFieldId set are shown only if the answer for parent field is given. Fields having parentFieldId and parentFieldValue set are displayed if the answer for parent field is given and it equals parentFieldValue.

Given answer is checked regarding to field's type (e.g. if type is "number" then the answer must be a number between min and max).

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table with id, category and field for the admin to use and relate them both using a common id field, preferably primary key. Now, this table can be queried for the reference of new categories inserted against a particular id in your main table. Use javascript/jquery to dynamically create html code for the new fields and show them on your page.

Suppose your the user selects Option 'A', then the new table can be queried to see if there are any fields set by the admin against the option 'A'. If yes, retrive those fields and show them to the user.